# Regex that matches files that don't end in test.js, but ends in .js

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-negation

Here is a list of sample strings to match against:

- These should be matched:

  ```
  hello.js
  test.hello.js
  test.js.js
  test.js.hello.js
  test.js.test.js.test.js.dss.js
  test.js.dss.js
  test.js.js.js.js.dummy.js
  ```
- These should not be matched:

  ```
  fun.css
  test.js
  fun.test.js
  test.test.js
  test.js.test.js
  hell.cs
  test.test.js
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple option is to use a negative lookahead to check the line does not end with `.test.js`:

```
^(?!.*\.test\.js$).*\.js$
```

That one doesn't cover `test.js`, which is a special case, but you can use `^(?!(?:^|.*\.)test\.js$).*\.js$` to get around it (or other similar options).

Working example: http://www.rubular.com/r/UVvRZMcnjl

If your flavor supports lookbehinds (JavaScript and old Ruby don't, but Ruby 1.9.2 does), you may use:

```
^.*(?<!^test|\.test)\.js$
```

Working example: http://www.rubular.com/r/lBCphNYEeS

Comment: Close, but fails on test.js.test.js.hello.js

Comment: works!! I fooled around and found this slightly different one. ^((?!.*\.test\.js$).)*\.js

Answer (score 2):

Since the question tags were changed from [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) to [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby), use a simple lookbehind:

```
.*(?<!test).js$
```

See it here in action: http://rubular.com/r/yVH2xfsRqw